# Indecomposable modules for the big quantum group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

I am study the representation theory of the big quantum group at a root of unity, and I am wonder if it is known a complete classification of the indecomposable modules for it. To be more specific, because the general question is hard to answer, Is it known a complete classification of indecomposable modules for the big quantum group of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ ?
I know there is a classification for the small quantum group of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, ("Indecomposable restricted representations for quantum $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, Chari & Premet), but for the big, I could't find any answer.

Comment: By biq quantum group you mean Lusztig's version of it?

Comment: Yes @JulianKuelshammer, It is the Lusztig's version of the quantum group.